# Get row count from a join table

Tags: php, mysql

I am pulling out rows from my database which will also show the number of responses to the post. I am able to grab the rows but need to do a count on the posts from a join table which takes the post_id and comment_id - I am not sure on how to approach this or if it is even doable?

```
function build_forum_featured(){    

    global $dbc;

    $q = "SELECT u.user_id, u.first_name, u.last_name, f.post_created, f.post_id, f.post_title, j.id 
             FROM users AS u
             INNER JOIN user_post_join AS j ON u.user_id = j.user_id
             INNER JOIN forum_post AS f ON f.post_id = j.post_id
             WHERE featured_post = 2
             ORDER BY post_created ASC
    ";  

    $r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q); // Run the query.



    // FETCH AND PRINT ALL THE RECORDS
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {

    echo '
    <div class="post">
        <div class="col-group-2">
            <a href="post_view.php?post_id='.$row["post_id"].'"><h3>'.$row["post_title"]. '</h3></a>
            <p>By: <a href="user_view.php?id=' . $row["user_id"] . '">'.$row["first_name"] . ' ' .$row["last_name"]. '</a> on: ' .date('d-m-Y', strtotime($row["post_created"])). '</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-group-2">
            <div class="post_count">
                <h3  class="answer">0</h3> // count goes here!
                <p class="answer">Responses</p>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
    ';

    }
```

Essentially what I a trykgi to do is reference the join table and check to see the post_id and how many comments are associated to that post. so I have a table called `comment_post_join` which takes the post_id and the comment_id and just adds rows.

Comment: @DrewPierce hey man i have updated my Q

Comment: use count() and group by in your query.

Comment: @nomistic where would the count() live?

Comment: @DrewPierce is the part of the query?

Comment: Google "select count using join MySQL" whole bunch of results leading back to Stack too ;-)

Comment: @DrewPierce I have placed it where you said and no errors show which is fab! buw how to I output the number? `<h3  class="answer">0</h3> // count goes here!`

Comment: Set count(*) as count. Then fetch your rows and retrieve it as any others.

Comment: If I understand right.... You want calculate how many comments there are per a post. Am I right? I do not see here something like comment_id in the output query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a count(*) to the list of your columns to select and add a group by user_id, post_id at the end of your statement...

Comment: But how do I output that?

Comment: I am seriously confused?

Comment: confused or not, as long as you do not specify your question, it is hard to answer...

Comment: @Anton - Sorry it is really simple what I am wanting to output but not explain. so I have a list of posts and on the row it shows ow many responses it has had. I guess I just need to count how many rows are in the join table byt the post id and how many comments are associated to it?

Comment: have you tried the way I suggested in my answer? because that should exactly do what you are asking for